# Powershell - get serial-number of android devices

Tags: android, powershell

enter code hereI am deploying Android packages to multiple devices using powershell (I am new to powershell). I get the list of devices using "adb devices", the output of which looks like this:

```
List of devices attached
ca677f63        device
emulator-5554   device
<blank line>
```

I want to get only the serial number of the devices. This is my attempt at it.

1) To skip the last blank line, I got the count of line numbers like this:

```
$devices=adb devices
$lines=($devices | measure-object -Line).lines
```

2) My final command is like this:

```
$deviceList=$devices | select -skip 1 | select -first ($lines-1) | foreach-object { $_ -replace('device')}
```

My question:  Is this the best way or is there a more cleaner and efficient way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try :

```
$devices=adb devices
$devices | where {$_ -match '(.*)device$'} | % {$Matches[1]}
```

I select with a regular expession, grouping needed caracters, all the lines ended with 'device'.